# VS Code - Select Current Word in JSON Files Includes Quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using `cmd+d` to select the current word in VS Code also annoyingly selects any quotes that may surround the word. Is there any way to prevent this?

Edit: This appears to only happen in JSON files.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior here, it only selects the word without quotes. Which vs code version do you have, on which OS, and for which document type?

Comment: I just realized it only apparently happens in JSON files. This is the current VS Code, on Mac.

Comment: VS Code uses the word definition of the language to determine the word, and that can't be configured by a setting (at least not afaik) the word separator settings are not used for that ([Use editor.wordSeparators for Ctrl+D multicursor #15774](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15774)). So either you fix it in the language config, fill an issue on github (but I guess that kind of bug will have really low priority), or you need to check if there is an extension that fixes that behavior.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the quotes selection with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> but I can with the `Expand Selection` command..

If you still have this issue. it may be fixed in vscode v1.69.  The quotes will no longer be considered part of a `json` word.  From the release notes:

> Every language comes with a word pattern that defines which characters
> belong to a word when in that language. JSON was different to all
> other language in that it included the quotes of string literals and
> the full string literal content. It now follows other languages and
> contains just letters, numbers and hyphens.
>
> The change will fix issues when expanding the selection (`Command: Expand Selection`), allow word completions inside strings and fix some
> quick suggestion abnormalities.